# Including markup elements in greensock splittext animation - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, gsap

In Greensocks SplitText you can split the text by `words, chars or lines`.
It kindly respects the markup within the text passed to it.

In my use case, I split the text by `words and chars`, then I animation through each character to animate it in.

Here is an example for what I am using.

**Text**

```
<div class="intro">
    Lorem dolor sit<br>
    <span class="icon-pin"></span> consectetur<br>
    adiposcing elit, sed do <span class="icon-hand"></span> lorem<br>
    ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var text = $('.intro');
    textTimeline = new TimelineMax;
    textSplitText = new SplitText(text, {
       type: "words,chars"
    });

textTimeline.staggerTo(textSplitText.chars, 1, {
    autoAlpha: 1,
    y: 0,
    delay: .3,
    ease: Power3.easeOut
}, .2);
```

I want some markup to be included in the `textSplitText.chars` array so that it will also animate.

What would be the best way to add each `span` or element with a particular class to the `textSplitText.chars` array putting the index in the correct place.

I did think about looking through the text and counting every character to the element I need to add and using that count to mark the place in the array to add the element.
But not sure this is the most efficient way.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.